# unable to load external reCAPTCHA dependencies when using auth to authenticate my mobile

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I started to auth mobile number the first step is verified by CAPTCHA

Then the webpage that verifying by CAPTCHA is loading but it stops suddenly and then I have the error below in the logs

> [firebase_auth/web-internal-error] unable to load external reCAPTCHA dependencies!

It is working on a device and one not.

I am runing on IOS device

Here it is my flutter doctor result

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm, locale en-EG)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at /Users/Home/flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (8 months ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Home/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 60.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 212.5284.31

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.54.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
    • iPhone 14 (mobile)          • E4D5DE76-9812-4DE2-9069-DA890CC69502 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-1 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.98

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Also you could find my AppDelegate that I am using on IOS

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
     override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
                let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
                firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
      }
      override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
                let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
                if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
                    print(userInfo)
                    return
                }
     }

}
```

Comment: enable Android Device Verification api in google cloud console https://console.cloud.google.com/

Comment: I have enabled it @NinadSawant and I had the same issue